# Changing multiple control properties at once

Tags: c#

I'm needing to change a bunch of properties in a large amount of controls. I'm having trouble getting it to work. Am I on the right track?

```
foreach(var c in this.Controls.OfType<Label>())
            {
                c.Text = "test";
            }
```

What's happening is var c is just creating a new object and not editing the existing one. How can I access the real control?

Comment: You are just looping through a collection of controls - 'c' is effectively a reference to that control - you are editing the existing control. What prensentation tech are you using? WinForms, WPF or ASP.Net?

Comment: I'm making a Windows App

Comment: it's a common question - see this answer, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1467980/1073107 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788490/c-how-can-i-iterate-through-all-checkboxes-on-a-form - I'm assuming you mean Windows Forms, here, though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1788757/1073107 is also very, very useful, and should do exactly what you need.

Comment: Ok, I have it working in my code. It was actually caused by a null object elsewhere which made me suspect it wasnt working... Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
foreach(var c in this.Controls)
{
    var label = c as Label;
    if(label != null) label.Text = "test";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can try this

```
 List<Control> controls = Controls.OfType<Label>().Cast<Control>().ToList();
  foreach (Control m in controls)
  {
      m.Text = "test";

  }
```